# MVC 4 _Layout.cshtml dynamic CSS

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a problem where I am trying to have a default CSS page, but depending on certain aspects can have their CSS changed. Groups of people can have their CSS changed to their own custom version via database entries, they post a long string that has what the CSS needs to be set to. But, they can also do something simple and simply want to overwrite maybe just the background or the entire site.

```
<head>
<link href="/static/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style type="text/css">
    @{
         WebExtensionHelper.CustomCSS();
     }
</style>
</head>
```

WebExtensionHelper.CustomCSS() returns a string with all the CSS in it, as stated previously. I need this to affect every page so I need this on the _Layout.cshtml page. Another thing to consider if it's helpful, I will have about 200 people who would like customcss.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to generate a custom CSS file at run time. In your layout you can point the stylesheet link to a controller action instead of an actual file:

```
<link href="@Url.Action("Index", "Style", new { whichStyle = myValue })" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

In the Style controller, create an Index method:

```
public ActionResult Index(string whichStyle)
{
    MyStyleViewModel model = new MyStyleViewModel();
    // -- (Load relevant style settings here) --
    Response.ContentType = "text/css";
    return View(model);
}
```

And then in the Index view, write out css as normal:

```
@model MyStyleViewModel
@{ Layout = null; }

body
{
color:#333;
@if (Model.Font == "Lucida")
{
    @:font-family:"Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}
else
{
    @:font-family:Georgia, Serif;
}
}
```

I haven't run that exact view code, so adjust as needed for your situation.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what exactly is going on here. In the view you write out some CSS code, but I don't know the CSS would be changed to. I only have a method that returns me a string of what the CSS would be, and the people who can change the css would like it so that they just have to update a database table to see the new changes on the site. I do have a default CSS page that they would also like to be able to overwrite bits and pieces of the page. So before switching to MVC I used to do this lazy thing where I would do something like this.

<style=css>
<%= CustomCSS() >
</style>

Comment: It helps if you have some idea what the CSS will look like, but if you have a CSS string in your controller you can just write that to your view directly using @Html.Raw or a similar helper. If you include your "default" CSS link before this one, then you will be effectively overwriting it without having to change it directly.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use LESS. It is supported in Visual Studio 2012 (and 2010) and MVC 4, so it is easy enough to use, and will do exactly what you want. It is perfect for your scenario.

Setting up LESS requires more work than I can put into an answer here, so as much as I hate to do this, here are two links:

- http://geekswithblogs.net/ToStringTheory/archive/2012/11/30/who-could-ask-for-more-with-less-css-part-2.aspx
- http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudio2012RCIsReleasedTheBigWebRollup.aspx
- http://richardneililagan.com/2012/08/automatic-dotless-compile-less-css/

Once set up you can either compile on the server side with [Dot LESS](http://www.dotlesscss.org/), as mentioned in the last link above, or send it to be processed [on client side with javascript](http://lesscss.org/).

Comment: I am unable to install packages at this time, so this solution will not work for me.

Comment: @user2406995. Less on the client side doesn't need a package, you just need to link to a copy of less.js, and send the less file to the client as you would a css file: http://lesscss.org/#usage

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
@WebExtensionHelper.CustomCSS();
```

not

```
 @{
  WebExtensionHelper.CustomCSS();
 }
```

Sorry for those who tried to help me earlier, I was unable to copy and paste my code at the time, and noticed in my question that I answered my problem.